# WCFExtras XmlComments ... Where Are They?

Tags: wcf, wcf-extensions

I spent the last 3 hours trying to get WCFExtras to output my XML comments to my WSDL using the steps they describe on the codeplex site among other places. Eventually I discovered WCFExtras was also generating a second WSDL available as a single file and that the XML comments were in *that* file.

My question is - since I can't find this information anywhere - is that how it's supposed to work? Is the intention of WCFExtras never to attempt to output the XML Comments in the WSDL WCF is already automatically generating? Am I supposed to generate this other WSDL file from now on if I am interested in having these comments?

I hope someone here knows. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but where was that second file in relation to the first, and how did you find it?  I'm working on the same problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, and I forgot to check the `XML documentation file` checkbox, on `Properties -> Build`. Thanks [Vo Thanh Vinh](http://vthanhvinh.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/wcfextras-and-xml-comment-doesnt-work.html).

[image]

Now, the WSDL includes the `wsdl:documentation` tags, but I have another problem: the `wsdl:documentation` contains the full XML documentation, including `<summary>` tags.

I'll update the answer if I find out something else.